# Cannot used GMail server in spring boot application

Tags: spring, server, smtp, gmail, imap

I don't know whether this is the right place to asked but anyway, I am trying to use gmail as a mail server in my Spring Boot Application. When I run it locally, I can sent the mail with out an error. But when I deploy in my server. There is an error. What could be the problem?

We have open all ports in the server

This is the error report: OPPS! Content not found |Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection| 500

HTML SCRIPT:

```
<form method="GET" action="/contactusSave" class="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Name</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Full Name" name="name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Subject</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Subject" name="subject">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group mt-3">
                    <label for="comment">Description:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" placeholder="Add Description" name="description"></textarea>
                </div>


                 <button class="admin-login-button login-button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("")
public class DemoController {

@Autowired
JavaMailSender sender;

@RequestMapping(value = "/contactusSave", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String contactusSave(@RequestParam("name") String username,
        @RequestParam("email") String email,
        @RequestParam("subject") String subject,
        @RequestParam("description") String description {


    System.out.println("email");
    String email = "*****@gmail.com";
    String body = "From: "+email +"\n" + "Description: "+ description;

    MyHelper.sendMail(sender,email, subject, body);   

    return "redirect:/index";
}
```

My Helper Class:

```
@Service
public class MyHelper {
public static void sendMail(JavaMailSender senders, String mEmail, String messageSubject, String messageBody) {

            SimpleMailMessage msg = new SimpleMailMessage();

            msg.setTo(mEmail);

            msg.setSubject(messageSubject);
            msg.setText(messageBody);
            senders.send(msg);

        }
}
```

Application Properties:

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=****@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=****

#new properties added
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true;
spring.mail.properties.mail.socketFactory.port=587
```

spring.mail.properties.mail.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFacto ry
    spring.mail.properties.mail.socketFactory.fallback=false

This is the new error message i get after adding new properties in the application properties file:
OPPS! Content not found |Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1; nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1; nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect| 500

Comment: The problem is that your so cannot acquire a JDBC connection, which has nothing to do with gmail. Does the content of the mail you are sending perhaps come from a database, to which you need a connection?

Comment: @arnt I am directly sending data coming from front-end to the mail. Not Using database for this one.

Comment: Your code does use a database. The error message says so clearly. Your problem is to find out why your code uses a database when you think you aren't using any. I'll vote to close this one since it's not detailed enough to understand or reproduce for anyone except you.

Comment: @arnt I have updated my question. Would you please look through it again if you are willing to?

Comment: put a breakpoint on the first line of that sendMail method - does it get hit (or rather: on what line does the exception occur)? What does `senders.send(msg)` do *exactly*?

Comment: In the Controller when i called the MyHelper.sendMail() exception occor. senders.send(msg) send the mail. One of the things that confuse me is that, when i run it locally in my machine the mail can be sent perfectly. But, when i build the .war file and deploy it in a server the exception occurs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. There was a problem with anti-virus in the server.